Closing Shell will result in missing events
Sample code:
public class Test {
    
    private static Listener listener = e -> {
        String type = null ;
        switch ( e.type ) {
            case SWT.MouseDown -> type = "MouseDown" ;
            case SWT.Activate -> type = "Activate" ;
            case SWT.Deactivate -> type = "Deactivate" ;
        }
       System.out.println( type + " - " + e ) ; 
    } ;
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Shell shell1 = new Shell() ;
        shell1.setText( "1" ) ;
        shell1.setSize( 300, 300 ) ;
        shell1.setLayout( new FillLayout() ) ;
        Composite composite1 = new Composite( shell1, SWT.NONE ) ;
        
        Shell shell2 = new Shell() ;
        shell2.setText( "2" ) ;
        shell2.setSize( 300, 300 ) ;
        shell2.setLayout( new FillLayout() ) ;
        Composite composite2 = new Composite( shell2, SWT.NONE ) ;
        
        addListeners( shell1 ) ;
        addListeners( composite1 ) ;
        addListeners( shell2 ) ;
        addListeners( composite2 ) ;
        // shell2.addListener( SWT.Deactivate, e -> shell2.close() ) ;
        
        shell1.open() ;
        shell2.open() ;
        
        Display display = shell1.getDisplay() ;
        
        while ( !shell1.isDisposed() ) {
            if ( !display.readAndDispatch() ) {
                display.sleep() ;
            }
        }
        display.dispose() ;
    }

    private static void addListeners( Control control ) {
        control.addListener( SWT.MouseDown, listener ) ;
        control.addListener( SWT.Activate, listener ) ;
        control.addListener( SWT.Deactivate, listener ) ;
    }

}

When shell2 is active and the mouse clicks on composite1, the event flow is as follows:
Activate - Event {type=26 Composite {} [layout=null] time=483235453 data=null x=0 y=0 width=0 height=0 detail=3}
Deactivate - Event {type=27 Shell {2} [layout=FillLayout {type=SWT.HORIZONTAL}] time=483235453 data=null x=0 y=0 width=0 height=0 detail=0}
Deactivate - Event {type=27 Composite {} [layout=null] time=483235453 data=null x=0 y=0 width=0 height=0 detail=0}
Activate - Event {type=26 Shell {1} [layout=FillLayout {type=SWT.HORIZONTAL}] time=483235453 data=null x=0 y=0 width=0 height=0 detail=3}
MouseDown - Event {type=3 Composite {} [layout=null] time=483236000 data=null x=187 y=115 width=0 height=0 detail=0}

However, closing it when shell2 deactivate,
shell2.addListener( SWT.Deactivate, e -> shell2.close() ) ;

results in the following event flow for the same mouse action:
Activate - Event {type=26 Composite {} [layout=null] time=483714125 data=null x=0 y=0 width=0 height=0 detail=3}
Deactivate - Event {type=27 Shell {*Disposed*} [layout=null] time=483714125 data=null x=0 y=0 width=0 height=0 detail=0}

Why are all the events after shell2 Deactivate gone?
What should I do if I still want to get the events after that?

I can't reproduce this on macOS with SWT from Eclipse 4.33

Yes, but this problem happened on Windows with SWT from Eclipse 4.33.
